# Python plotting: How can I make matplotlib.pyplot stop forcing the style of my markers?

Tags: python, coding-style, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a bunch of data points (many thousands) in Python using [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/index.html) so I need each marker to be very small and precise.  How do I get the smallest most simple marker possible?  I use this command to plot my data:

```
 matplotlib.pyplot( x , y ,'.',markersize=0.1,linewidth=None,markerfacecolor='black')
```

Then I can look at it either with `pl.show()` and then save it.  Or directly use `plt.savefig('filename.ps')` in the code to save it.  The problem is this: when I use `pl.show()` to view the file in the GUI it looks great with small tiny black marks, however when I save from the `show()` GUI to a file or use directly `savefig` and then view the `ps` I created it looks different!  Each marker has gained a little blue halo around it (as if it started at each point to connect them with the default blue lines, but did not) and the style is all wrong.  Why does it change the style when saved?  How do I stop python from forcing the style of the markers?  And yes I have looked at some alternative packages like [CairoPlot](http://linil.wordpress.com/2008/09/16/cairoplot-11/), but I want to keep using matplotlib for now.

**Update:** It turns out that the save to PNG first makes the colors turn out okay, but it forces a conversion of the image when I want to save it again as a `.ps` later (for inclusion in a PDF) and then I lose quality.  How do I preserve the vector nature of the file and get the right formatting?

Comment: Well, for ploting points, the trunk version of CairoPlot has the ScatterPlot class. Using that you can define the radius of the marker, so you might just set it to 1 as it would be the smallest option. Is there any special reason for you not to use CairoPlot?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For nice-looking vectorized output, don't use the `'.'` marker style. Use e.g. `'o'` (circle) or `'s'` (square) (see `help(plot)` for the options) and set the `markersize` keyword argument to something suitably small, e.g.:

```
plot(x, y, 'ko', markersize=2)
savefig('foo.ps')
```

That `'.'` (point) produces less nice results could be construed as a bug in matplotlib, but then, what *should* "point" mean in a vector graphic format?

Comment: for saving time) if `markersize` is very small eg 0.1, the circle becomes "empty"(not filled), and `'.'`(dot) also becomes empty circle in this case. `','`(pixel) might be better if one wants the _smallest_ marker(`markersize` option doesn't apply in this case). I'm not sure if these results are consistent with different backends, though.

Answer (score 10):

Have you tried the `','` point shape? It creates "[pixels](http://matplotlib.org/api/markers_api.html)" (small dots, instead of shapes).

You can play with the `markersize` option as well, with this shape?

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't, you should try saving in a rasterizing engine -- save it to a PNG file and see if that fixes it.  If you need a vector plot, try saving to PDF and converting with an external utility.  I've also had problems before with the PS engine that were resolved by saving with the Agg or PDF engines and converting externally.

Comment: Yeah, this work around works.  BTW we do the same kind of work.